# Instructions needed to integrate spring-security-ui into my grails application

Tags: grails, spring-security

First things first, I have already started going through these URLs to install the spring-security-ui to my grails application.

[Spring Security UI Plugin](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-ui/docs/manual/guide/1%20Introduction%20to%20the%20Spring%20Security%20UI%20Plugin.html)

and ...

[Customizing Grails Spring Security Plugin](http://www.objectpartners.com/2011/05/24/customizing-the-grails-spring-security-ui-plugin/)

I already have spring-security-core installed and working on my application. I was able to create all the access controls for gsp elements and also controller actions. That's done. Now, my requirement was to provide a UI to manage the User, Role and Access so that some admin can use it for ease.

Note: While integrating spring-security-core, I chose the doman classes to be SecureUser, SecureRole and Requestmap as the domains to be generated ( instead of the default User, Role and Requestmap ). But yes, that is working perfectly.

Steps that I followed:

1. Added the plugin dependency *compile ":spring-security-ui:0.2"*
2. Ran command: *grails install-plugin spring-security-ui*
3. This returns a success message with a warning that *install-plugin* command is depecretated and will be replaced in future versions ... which I need not worry about for now.
4. I do a *grails run-app* and I see a huge stacktrace ( which I would paste at the end of the question ).

So, my questions are:

1. Once I see a success message after installing the plug-in, what I am supposed to see in the application? Will it not create any Controllers or Domains or Views to provide the UI?
2. Is there any step that I am missing? until Step 4? I assume that should give me a basic interface/UI to manage Users ( unless I want to customize like in the objectpartners URL I gave above ).

Also, the error that I see when I do run-app is:

```
| Loading Grails 2.2.1
| Configuring classpath
| Configuring classpath.
| Environment set to development
| Environment set to development.
| Environment set to development..
| Environment set to development...
| Environment set to development....
| Environment set to development.....
| Packaging Grails application
| Packaging Grails application.
| Packaging Grails application..
| Packaging Grails application...
| Packaging Grails application....
| Compiling 1 source files
| Compiling 1 source files.
| Compiling 1 source files..
| Compiling 1 source files...
| Compiling 1 source files....
| Compiling 1 source files.....
| Compiling 1 source files.....
2013-05-21 15:34:27,535 [main] WARN  webxml.WebxmlGrailsPlugin  - Did not find application config file: WebXmlConfig
2013-05-21 15:34:28,130 [main] WARN  webxml.WebxmlGrailsPlugin  - Did not find application config file: WebXmlConfig
| Running Grails application

Configuring Spring Security UI ...
... finished configuring Spring Security UI

2013-05-21 15:34:32,508 [localhost-startStop-1] WARN  util.GrailsUtil  - [DEPRECATED] Method ConfigurationHolder.getConfig() is deprecated and will be removed in a future version of Grails.

Configuring Spring Security Core ...
... finished configuring Spring Security Core

2013-05-21 15:34:34,080 [localhost-startStop-1] WARN  config.ConfigurationFactory  - No configuration found. Configuring ehcache from ehcache-failsafe.xml  found in the classpath: jar:file:/C:/Users/ramarajuv/.grails/ivy-cache/net.sf.ehcache/ehcache-core/jars/ehcache-core-2.4.6.jar!/ehcache-failsafe.xml
2013-05-21 15:34:35,633 [localhost-startStop-1] WARN  util.GrailsUtil  - [DEPRECATED] Method ApplicationHolder.getApplication() is deprecated and will be removed in a future version of Grails.
2013-05-21 15:34:37,391 [localhost-startStop-1] WARN  servlet.DefaultGrailsApplicationAttributes  - ApplicationContext not found in org.codehaus.groovy.grails.APPLICATION_CONTEXT attribute of servlet context.
2013-05-21 15:34:38,402 [localhost-startStop-1] WARN  module.ModuleDeclarationsFactory  - 'grails.resources.modules' in config does not define any modules
2013-05-21 15:34:38,571 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR StackTrace  - Full Stack Trace:
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot get property 'name' on null object
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.NullObject.getProperty(NullObject.java:56)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.getProperty(InvokerHelper.java:169)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.NullCallSite.getProperty(NullCallSite.java:44)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:227)
    at org.grails.plugin.resource.ResourceProcessor$_updateDependencyOrder_closure4.doCall(ResourceProcessor.groovy:117)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1243)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:272)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.call(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:64)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
    at org.grails.plugin.resource.ResourceProcessor$_updateDependencyOrder_closure4.doCall(ResourceProcessor.groovy:124)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1243)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:272)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.call(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:64)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
    at org.grails.plugin.resource.ResourceProcessor.updateDependencyOrder(ResourceProcessor.groovy:131)
    at org.grails.plugin.resource.ResourceProcessor.loadModules(ResourceProcessor.groovy:804)
    at org.grails.plugin.resource.ResourceProcessor.this$2$loadModules(ResourceProcessor.groovy)
    at org.grails.plugin.resource.ResourceProcessor$this$2$loadModules.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:49)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
    at org.grails.plugin.resource.ResourceProcessor.reloadAll(ResourceProcessor.groovy:1075)
    at org.grails.plugin.resource.ResourceProcessor$reloadAll.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:112)
    at ResourcesGrailsPlugin$_closure3.doCall(ResourcesGrailsPlugin.groovy:172)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1243)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1082)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1106)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:906)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:412)
    at ResourcesGrailsPlugin$_closure3.call(ResourcesGrailsPlugin.groovy)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.DefaultGrailsPlugin.doWithDynamicMethods(DefaultGrailsPlugin.java:703)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.DefaultGrailsPluginManager.doDynamicMethods(DefaultGrailsPluginManager.java:741)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.GrailsRuntimeConfigurator.configure(GrailsRuntimeConfigurator.java:174)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.GrailsRuntimeConfigurator.configure(GrailsRuntimeConfigurator.java:127)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsConfigUtils.configureWebApplicationContext(GrailsConfigUtils.java:121)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(GrailsContextLoader.java:107)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4791)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5285)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
2013-05-21 15:34:38,575 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR StackTrace  - Full Stack Trace:
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot get property 'name' on null object
    at org.grails.plugin.resource.ResourceProcessor$_updateDependencyOrder_closure4.doCall(ResourceProcessor.groovy:117)
    at org.grails.plugin.resource.ResourceProcessor$_updateDependencyOrder_closure4.doCall(ResourceProcessor.groovy:124)
    at org.grails.plugin.resource.ResourceProcessor.updateDependencyOrder(ResourceProcessor.groovy:131)
    at org.grails.plugin.resource.ResourceProcessor.loadModules(ResourceProcessor.groovy:804)
    at org.grails.plugin.resource.ResourceProcessor.reloadAll(ResourceProcessor.groovy:1075)
    at ResourcesGrailsPlugin$_closure3.doCall(ResourcesGrailsPlugin.groovy:172)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
2013-05-21 15:34:38,576 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR resource.ResourceProcessor  - Unable to load resources
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot get property 'name' on null object
    at org.grails.plugin.resource.ResourceProcessor$_updateDependencyOrder_closure4.doCall(ResourceProcessor.groovy:117)
    at org.grails.plugin.resource.ResourceProcessor$_updateDependencyOrder_closure4.doCall(ResourceProcessor.groovy:124)
    at org.grails.plugin.resource.ResourceProcessor.updateDependencyOrder(ResourceProcessor.groovy:131)
    at org.grails.plugin.resource.ResourceProcessor.loadModules(ResourceProcessor.groovy:804)
    at org.grails.plugin.resource.ResourceProcessor.reloadAll(ResourceProcessor.groovy:1075)
    at ResourcesGrailsPlugin$_closure3.doCall(ResourcesGrailsPlugin.groovy:172)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
2013-05-21 15:34:40,084 [localhost-startStop-1] WARN  util.GrailsUtil  - [DEPRECATED] Method ConfigurationHolder.getConfig() is deprecated and will be removed in a future version of Grails.
2013-05-21 15:34:40,092 [localhost-startStop-1] WARN  util.GrailsUtil  - [DEPRECATED] Method ApplicationHolder.getApplication() is deprecated and will be removed in a future version of Grails.
2013-05-21 15:34:40,103 [localhost-startStop-1] WARN  util.GrailsUtil  - [DEPRECATED] Method ApplicationHolder.getApplication() is deprecated and will be removed in a future version of Grails.
2013-05-21 15:34:40,186 [localhost-startStop-1] WARN  util.GrailsUtil  - [DEPRECATED] Method ConfigurationHolder.getConfig() is deprecated and will be removed in a future version of Grails.
2013-05-21 15:34:40,191 [Thread-10] ERROR plugins.DefaultGrailsPlugin  - Cannot generate controller logic for scaffolded class true. It is not a domain class!
2013-05-21 15:34:40,670 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR StackTrace  - Full Stack Trace:
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot get property 'name' on null object
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.NullObject.getProperty(NullObject.java:56)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.getProperty(InvokerHelper.java:169)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.NullCallSite.getProperty(NullCallSite.java:44)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:227)
    at org.grails.plugin.resource.ResourceProcessor$_updateDependencyOrder_closure4.doCall(ResourceProcessor.groovy:117)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
...
...
...
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
2013-05-21 15:34:40,847 [Thread-10] ERROR StackTrace  - Full Stack Trace:
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationNotAllowedException: Error creating bean with name 'instanceControllersApi': Singleton bean creation not allowed while the singletons of this factory are in destruction (Do not request a bean from a BeanFactory in a destroy method implementation!)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:212)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.ReloadAwareAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireBeanInAutowireByName(ReloadAwareAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:201)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.ReloadAwareAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBeanInAutowireByName(ReloadAwareAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.ReloadAwareAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireBeanProperties(ReloadAwareAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:181)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.AutowireCapableBeanFactory$autowireBeanProperties.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.AutowireCapableBeanFactory$autowireBeanProperties.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.scaffolding.ScaffoldingGrailsPlugin.configureScaffoldingController(ScaffoldingGrailsPlugin.groovy:116)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.scaffolding.ScaffoldingGrailsPlugin$configureScaffoldingController.callStatic(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.scaffolding.ScaffoldingGrailsPlugin.configureScaffolding(ScaffoldingGrailsPlugin.groovy:90)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1243)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1082)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1106)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:906)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1027)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1106)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:906)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:727)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyObjectSupport.invokeMethod(GroovyObjectSupport.java:44)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethodOnGroovyObject(MetaClassImpl.java:1147)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1041)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1106)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:906)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:66)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:49)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:145)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.scaffolding.ScaffoldingGrailsPlugin$_closure2_closure10.doCall(ScaffoldingGrailsPlugin.groovy:77)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.scaffolding.ScaffoldingGrailsPlugin$_closure2_closure10.doCall(ScaffoldingGrailsPlugin.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1243)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1082)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1106)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:906)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:412)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:406)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.run(Closure.java:490)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
2013-05-21 15:34:40,849 [Thread-10] ERROR StackTrace  - Full Stack Trace:
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationNotAllowedException: Error creating bean with name 'instanceControllersApi': Singleton bean creation not allowed while the singletons of this factory are in destruction (Do not request a bean from a BeanFactory in a destroy method implementation!)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
2013-05-21 15:34:40,849 [Thread-10] ERROR plugins.DefaultGrailsPlugin  - Error configuration scaffolding: Error creating bean with name 'instanceControllersApi': Singleton bean creation not allowed while the singletons of this factory are in destruction (Do not request a bean from a BeanFactory in a destroy method implementation!)
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationNotAllowedException: Error creating bean with name 'instanceControllersApi': Singleton bean creation not allowed while the singletons of this factory are in destruction (Do not request a bean from a BeanFactory in a destroy method implementation!)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Comment: You do not need step 2, if you are following step 1. Try `grails clean && grails compile && grails run-app`.

Comment: tried that as well but grails run-app still throws the error that I pasted. Any answers to the two questions?

Comment: Looks like you are getting NPE from Resources plugin. Which version of resources plugin are you using? Use the latest one [v1.2](http://grails.org/plugin/resources)

Comment: The dependency is already in place and it's v1.2.

Comment: Then I would check if there is `staleReference.name` used in any JS file which is causing the NPE. Search for `name` in all JS files in project and diagnose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you install all the plugins `spring-security-ui` depends on? They are NOT installed automatically, as stated in the [documentation](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-ui/docs/manual/guide/1%20Introduction%20to%20the%20Spring%20Security%20UI%20Plugin.html). You could be missing the `jquery`, `jquery-ui` and `famfamfam` plugins which register certain resources `spring-security-ui` needs, that would explain the stacktrace you are seeing.

Comment: May be it's the famfamfam ... I ignored that.

Comment: I installed jquery and famfamfam plugins as well. The only things I don't have are mail and jquery-ui which I don't think are mandatory except when I want to avail the mailing feature.

Comment: jquery-ui is not optional, a resource module declaration dependsOn it. Either install the plugin or create an empty 'jquery-ui' resource module yourself (though you'll probably get client side errors in that case).